# PhpStorm VCS update error: cannot spawn

Tags: php, version-control, phpstorm

I receive error while trying to update my VCS on PhpStorm.

I just made commit on  git and tried to update it from PhpStorm but I kept getting this error.

```
Fetch failed
            error: cannot spawn C:\Users\ali\.PhpStorm2016.2\system\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.bat: No such file or directory
            error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
            fatal: could not read Password for 'https://libedux@bitbucket.org': No error
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this "intellij-git-askpass.bat: No such file or directory" for hours (the file was in place, no antivirus was blocking it, moving config directory didn't work etc), what worked was:

1. exporting settings
2. importing settings from other jetbrains product (it had no such issue, although it may not be necessary)
3. importing the settings from step 1

Yes I didn't find the cause, but the above steps worked for me, so It may save some people hours of work.

Answer (score -1):

i found solution by writing this on git console

git pull origin master